# PdfHandler preview image of pdf failing on Debian buster

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I am trying to get the [PdfHandler](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:PdfHandler) extension to show previews of pdf files on a MediaWiki running on a Debian buster OS.  The following is from the wiki `Version` page.

[image]

The problem seems to be related to `poppler-utils` because when I look at a pdf file's metadata it shows it has dimensions of `0 x 0` pixel as described [here under Pre-requisites](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:PdfHandler).
[image]

Based on that this should indicate that I don't have xpdf-utils or poppler-utils installed - **but I do** have poppler-utils installed.

The result of `which gs convert pdfinfo pdftotext` is as follows:

```
/usr/bin/gs 
/usr/bin/convert 
/usr/bin/pdfinfo 
/usr/bin/pdftotext
```

Here are the relevant settings in `LocalSettings.php':

```
wfLoadExtension( 'PdfHandler' );
# adding stuff so PdfHandler can provide preview images of pdf's
$wgPdfProcessor = '/usr/bin/gs';
$wgPdfPostProcessor = '/usr/bin/convert'; 
$wgPdfInfo = '/usr/bin/pdfinfo';
$wgPdftoText = '/usr/bin/pdftotext';
```

The result of `php -m | grep imagick` is `imagick` as expected.  I have rebooted the machine too.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have this extension working under Ubuntu. However, I had `apt install ghostscript poppler-utils netpbm`.

Comment: Check your [error logs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:How_to_debug#Logging), especially the `exec` and `XMP` channels.

Comment: @AlexanderMashin thank you.  When I run `apt install ghostscript poppler-utils netpbm` the result is that `ghostscript`, `netpbm`, and `poppler-utils` are all 3 `already the newest version`.  I will look at the error logs per @Tgr suggestion tomorrow.